# Azure NodeJS version

Tags: node.js, angular, azure

Ok I give up.  Why does Azure have some default version of node (0.10.x for gawds sake) and then relies on using hard-coded paths for the specific version required?  That was not my question (it was rhetorical).

The problem with this arrangement is that it seems that "internal" (to the app) calls are made to node and of course the one in $PATH is used.

We have an nodejs, express, angular app.

My first problem (though not the causes for this post) was that I have nested `package.json` files in `/, angular/ and server/` directories.  The root one calls install on the sub-directories.  This does not work in Azure.

I had to move the calls to `gulp` and `ng` out to the Azure `deploy.sh` by making hard-coded references to the installed node modules.  The `deploy.sh` contains:

```
#!/bin/bash

...
NODE_EXE=`cat "$DEPLOYMENT_TEMP/__nodeVersion.tmp"`
NPM_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" \"$NPM_JS_PATH\""
GRUNT_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" ./node_modules/gulp/bin/gulp.js"
NG_CMD="\"$NODE_EXE\" ./node_modules/@angular/cli/bin/ng"

...

cd server
eval $NPM_CMD install --production
eval $GRUNT_CMD build

cd ../angular
eval $NPM_CMD install --production
eval $NG_CMD build --prod

cd ..
```

As part of the NG production build is a mimification step.  It appears to have an 'internal node call' and is failing:

```
remote: Selected node.js version 10.14.1. Use package.json file to choose a different version.
remote: Selected npm version 6.4.1
...
...
...
remote: Date: 2019-01-04T04:20:42.367Z
remote: ERROR in ./src/styles.scss
remote: Hash: 8062ccafe553f9f5894b
remote: Time: 33752ms
remote: chunk {0} runtime.ec2944dd8b20ec099bf3.js (runtime) 1.41 kB [entry] [rendered]
remote: chunk {1} main.9868d9b237c3a48c54da.js (main) 128 bytes [initial] [rendered]
remote: chunk {2} polyfills.85f47f0bf59079cbc23a.js (polyfills) 130 bytes [initial] [rendered]
remote: chunk {3}  (styles) [initial] [rendered]
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote: Module build failed (from D:/home/site/wwwroot/angular/node_modules/mini-css-extract-plugin/dist/loader.js):
remote: ng build in angular failed
remote: ModuleBuildError: Module build failed (from D:/home/site/wwwroot/angular/node_modules/sass-loader/lib/loader.js):
remote: Error: Missing binding D:\home\site\wwwroot\angular\node_modules\node-sass\vendor\win32-ia32-64\binding.node
remote: Node Sass could not find a binding for your current environment: Windows 32-bit with Node.js 10.x
remote:
remote: Found bindings for the following environments:
remote:   - Windows 32-bit with Node 0.10.x
```

The `./src/styles.scss` contains:

```
@import '~@dhsui/kit/styles/dhs-kit-all';
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

I tried making a change to prepend the desired version of node directory to the PATH (and changed to just calling `node` rather than the full path that Azure seems to require you to do):

```
NODE_DIR=$(dirname "$(echo $NODE_EXE | tr '\\' '/')" | tr '/' '\\')
export PATH=$NODE_DIR:$PATH
```

But it failed at the same place.  So it seems my problem is not `that "internal" (to the app) calls are made to node and of course the one in $PATH is used.`!  (This change actually didn't work so I reverted).

Does anyone know why the binding has been setup for `Node 0.10.x` and what can be done to prevent this problem?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is a wiki page [`Node versioning`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Node-versioning) of Project Kudu for Azure WebApps which can answer your question about Node version. Before Oct 31, 2017 when the wiki page be edited， the default node version is `v0.6.20`, now it is `0.10.40`. It seems to be up to the deployment template of Azure WebApps.

After your webapp was created, you can configure the value of Azure [Website environment variable](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Azure-runtime-environment#website-environment-variables) `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` to change the default Node version in the tab `Application settings` of Azure portal, as the figure below, like the subsection [`Change the Node version`](https://github.com/projectkudu/kudu/wiki/Configurable-settings#change-the-node-version) of the wiki page `Configurable settings` said.

[image]

About the all available Node versions in Azure WebApps, you can command `ls` under the path `D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs` of Kudu console to list them as the figure below.

[image]

After you set the `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION`, your website will autorestart and the Node version has been upgraded.

[image]

Then you can make your script works directly on the current Node version, without considering for these environment variables like `PATH` or others about Node.

Comment: Thanks Peter, that looks like it may solve the problem I have a question for and the other problem I highlighted (but had a work-a-round for - by moving steps to the `deploy.sh`).  I have an answer that addresses my latest problem (the question) and will post that.  I will aim to try deploying a new version to test your answer.

Comment: It is a problem to me that this might be the solution.  It means that over time you will need to keep this setting in Sync with the application (versioned in a repository).

Comment: Great thanks Peter that worked.  I'll just have to make it clear that major or possibly minor Semver changes to the version of nodejs we use will require this be changed also.  I still don't understand why Azure doesn't just create a symlink from `.../nodejs` to `nodeversions\x.y.z` and prevent this problem.

Answer (score 0):

I had to

```
npm rebuild node-sass
```

before running the `ng build --production`.

I found a note about this buried in the error message.  I originally dismissed this as the `npm install` was run just prior to the `ng build` so it seemed redundant.  Not so apparently!

I didn't find out WHY `nodejs 0.10.x` was being referenced in some way.

---

I've just received an Answer from @PeterPan about choosing default nodejs versions.  That may answer why a different version is being used (because there is a default that fortunately can be chosen).  I aim to test out Peter's answer.

---

I don't like the way Azure (Windows NT server at least) node installs don't work exactly the same way as on my MacOSX box.  Node is cross-platform and should behave the same everywhere (bar for platform specific modules like `fsevents`).  I believe this to be a failure.  As a reminder, I have one way for Mac / Linux and another for Azure.

I will alternatively try and install this node / express / angular web app on Linux under Azure and see if that is better (unfortunately where I work is locked in to thinking 'Windows' so I don't think I will gain much ground that way).

Kudos to Microsoft for allowing the use of bash scripts.

Comment: NOTE that @PeterPans' solution is much better.