# Can't deploy node project: Maximum call stack size exceeded

Tags: node.js, azure, npm

I have been trying to deploy to MS Azure all day but I'm running into a very frustrating problem. This is what I get when trying to push:

```
remote: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded
remote:
remote: npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
remote: npm ERR!     D:\local\AppData\npm-cache\_logs\2019-09-02T13_35_12_766Z-debug.log
remote: Failed exitCode=1, command="D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs\10.14.1\node.exe" "D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\bin\npm-cli.js" install --production
remote: An error has occurred during web site deployment.
remote:
remote: Error - Changes committed to remote repository but deployment to website failed.
```

The logs in Azure are a bit more informative. They point to `deps.js`, which as far as I can tell, is a native node module:

```
...
verbose stack     at RegExp.test (<anonymous>)
verbose stack     at isDepOptional (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:405:45)
verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:414:9)
verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
verbose stack     at failedDependency (D:\Program Files (x86)\npm\6.4.1\node_modules\npm\lib\install\deps.js:430:9)
...
```

My guess is that my VM's node is broken. In that case, how can I fix it? I tried `npm update -g`, but I don't have sudo privileges. I also tried to change the version number flag, but the problem persists.

Any suggestions and observations are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you have tried to deploy a NodeJS app on Azure WebApp, but got the error `remote: npm ERR! Maximum call stack size exceeded`.

Per my experience, there are two ways to fix it that you can try.

1. Try to clean the npm cache in the path `D:\local\AppData\npm-cache` via command `npm cache clean` or the same command with option `-f`, then to do your operations again.
2. To upgrade or downgrade the npm version via upgrade or downgrade the value of environment variable `WEBSITE_NODE_DEFAULT_VERSION` for Node version, please refer to my answer for the other SO thread [Azure NodeJS version](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54034084/azure-nodejs-version/54070657#54070657) and the new figure below. The available Node version on Azure WebApp which you can list via command `ls "D:\Program Files (x86)\nodejs"`. The npm version will be changed by following the node version changed. Then to do your operations again.

   [image]